# Can every language of context-free grammar be expressed in set builder notation?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Is it true that every [CFG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) can be written as [CFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) just by using set builder notation and basic algebraic terms?

For example CFG named $G$:

$$S \rightarrow a\,S\,b\,\,|\,\,\epsilon$$

Can be written as following CFL:

$$L(G)=\{\, a^nb^n\,\,|\,\,n \ge 0\}$$

Does it hold generally?

Comment: What is your precise definition of *set builder notation*?